# Navigation to new html page using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working in angular.js. Using ng-view navigate in body section. If i need to navigate to a new html page. How we can achieve in angular.js. Is there any angular.js directives in angular.js.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Learn routing in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You should go through following things for routing:

[Angular ui-route](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)

[Angular ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In the header and footer be common only main only navigate when link click. But i need if i click a link it will navigate to new html page. How it is possible in angular.js

Comment: There are two thing, do you want to navigate to next page or html view template. Let me give you some example of the same [Route implementation](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/about)

Answer (score 0):

Angular-UI-Router is more powerful directive than ngRoute. Following code is what i had tried sometimes before. hope it will also help you.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']); //Inject `ui.router` directive inside your `app` module

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',                
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
        })
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular Routing</title>    
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/controllers/homeCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <div ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**templates/header.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">Angular</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

templates/footer.html

```
<p>&copy; SJ</p>
```

**templates/home.html**

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

**templates/about.html**

```
<h1>About<h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But my exact problem is new page have different design. Its not using header and the footer only common.

Comment: by using routing configuration you can redirect to any page you want. btw, have you tried above sample code?